# Why is using [x] to generate random keypairs a bad idea?

Tags: key-generation, random

Anyone who has generated large GPG public/private keypairs has come across this annoying message: *"Not enough random bytes available. Please do some other work to give the OS a chance to collect more entropy!"*

Searching for answers, you will often find answers such as these:

> Use `rngd -r /dev/urandom` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618204/617937)] [[2](https://serverfault.com/a/214618/97027)]
>   Install and use `rng-tools` [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716881/617937)]
>   Make a symlink so `/dev/urandom` is used instead of `/dev/random` [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23605030/617937)]

After which you find a comment (usually with a distinct lack of explanation, just a violent outburst):

> [Oh my god](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY0Fl.jpg), that's a horrible idea!!

**Why** are these alternative methods of generating random keypairs a bad idea? What makes waiting for `/dev/random` to finish so much more secure?

Comment: I'm assuming all the aforementioned tools are a bad idea because they are _pseudo_ random number generators. I ask the question anyway because it would be nice to have a proper Q/A that can be linked to when these types of answers pop up.

Answer (score 8):

`rng-tools` acts as a bridge between your computer's hardware random-number generator (if it has one) and `/dev/random`  If you trust your computer's hardware RNG, there's nothing wrong with using it.  If, on the other hand, you *don't* have a hardware RNG, `rng-tools` can be used to make the kernel think there's more randomness in its entropy pool than there actually is.

The problem with the suggestion in your first link (`rngd -r /dev/urandom`) is that you're feeding the output of the kernel's entropy pool back into it, and pretending that this represents new data.  Likewise, the "symlink `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom`" suggestion in the third link forces `gpg` to use a source of not-necessarily-high-grade randomness when it's expecting a source of high-grade randomness.

The problem with using low-grade randomness when generating RSA keypairs is that if your keypair shares a factor with someone else's keypair, there's a [trivial attack](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf) that can deduce your private key from your public key (use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the GCD of the two public keys, which is one of the prime factors, then use simple division to compute the other prime).  This is particularly a problem with embedded systems that generate a keypair on first boot, when they don't have much if any entropy available.